# If the pressure between the cross-sections of a pipe is equal, will $P_1$ and $P_2$ be cancelled out of Bernoulli's Equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

> **a).** Water is flowing through a pipe of two circular cross- sections area $A_1$ and $A_2$ lying horizontally as shown in figure below. The pressure difference between the cross-section $A_1$ and $A_2$ is 7500 Pascals. If the velocity of the water through cross-section $A_1$ is $3.25\ \mathrm{m/s}$, what would be the velocity of the water through cross-section $A_2$?
>
> [image: image of pipe with varying cross-section]

Using Bernoulli's Equation, I tried rearranging the equation so that it can be used to answer a problem like the one above.
$$P_1 + \rho gh_1 + 1/2 \rho v^2_1 = P_1 + \rho gh_2 + 1/2 \rho v^2_2$$
Height is constant. Therefore equation will be:
$$P_1 + 1/2 \rho v^2_1 = P_2 + 1/2 \rho v^2_2$$
**My question:** Since the pressure is constant, will $P_1$ and $P_2$ be removed from the equation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41116/discussion-on-question-by-augiejavax98-if-the-pressure-between-the-cross-section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Summary of discussion on this question between AugieJavax98, philip_0008 and sammy_gerbil :*

$P_1$ is not equal to $P_2$.  The question says that there is a "pressure difference" between $A_1$ and $A_2$.  The height $h$ is assumed to be the same at both ends (the pipe is lying horizontally).  The difference in area causes a difference in flow speed (continuity equation) and a difference in pressure (Bernoulli equation).

The illustration suggests that $A_2 > A_1$. Therefore $P_2 > P_1$.  However, this leads to an imaginary value for $v_2$, the speed through $A_2$.

However, the illustration could be misleading.  The text does not state that $A_2 > A_1$.  Assuming instead that $A_1 > A_2$ and therefore $P_1 > P_2$ leads to a real (and realistic) value for $v_2$ :

$$P_1 + \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2_1 = P_2 + \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2_2$$ 
$$P_1 - P_2  = \frac{1}{2} \rho (v^2_2 - v_1^2)$$ 
$$7500Pa = \frac{1}{2} (1000kg/m^3)(v^2_2 - (3.25m/s)^2)$$ 
which gives $$v=5.06m/s$$.